# Drupal: Displaying two content types on same page

Tags: php, drupal-7, content-type

I'm new to `drupal` and dev in general so please bear with me whilst I try to explain what I mean. I hope this isn't a super nooby question?

In the `admin` bar I have two content types:

- Structure > Content Types > Project

  - Has field: field_teaser_image_2
- Structure > Content Types > Flexible Layout

  - Has field: field_listing_image

I am currently editing the file `node--project.tpl.php`.

In that file I have this piece of code:

```
<?php if ($content['field_teaser_image_2']): ?>

  <?php print render($content['field_teaser_image_2']); ?>

<?php elseif (empty($content['field_listing_image'])): ?>

  <?php print render($content['field_listing_image']); ?>

<?php else: ?>

  <img src="/<?php print path_to_theme(); ?>/images/site-logo.png" alt=" " class="associated-content__image__default">

<?php endif; ?>
```

The problem is with this line:

```
<?php print render($content['field_listing_image']); ?>
```

for some reason it is returning blank. When I use:

```
var_dump($content);
```

then the field `'field_listing_image'` is not in the result.

I might be wrong but I think it's because the scope of `$content` is defined by the page I am on. So it is only getting content that is related to `node--project`.

If I am right then I need a way to access another variable out of this loop.

Can anyone see what I mean and show me how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your explanation rigth, you hace 2 content types:

- Project
- Flexible Layout

There is not way to render field_listing_image on the node--project.tpl.php template. Actually, there is not any relation between the Project content type and 
field_listing_image field. So, that's imposible to render a field that not belong or it's related to the content type.

You need to reused field_listing_image on the Project content type, or just create a new field. There is another option, you can use a reference field, take a look a this module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/field_reference

I hope this help.

Comment: You said: `You need to reused field_listing_image on the Project content type` - how do I do this?

Comment: Structure > Content Types > Project > Managment Fields  , then, you can choose your 'field_listing_image' field in the 'Add existing field' dropdown. But remember, in this case, you will only have a field with the same name and same features in two differents content types, so, it will save different data for Projects and Flexible Layout content type.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that even if I set that content field up in flexible layouts, the node--project will not be able to get it because it saves it in a different place ?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that. But you can create only one content type with a lot of fields. Or even you can reference a field from Project that has data, when you create a new Flexible Layout  content.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Drupal the best way to achieve this is using views - no need to write a single line of code here.

1.Create two blocks into views one is for Project and the other one is for Flexible Layout content type.

now you have two blocks which are listing each CT separately.

2.Go to admin>structure>block and assign both blocks into content region, restrict them to those two content types only

3.Go to admin>structure>content type> manage display and hide all fields from default view (so you get blocks rendered only). And that is it.

Answer (score 0):

`$content` will contain the rendered output and some of the raw information used for rendering the current page. So if you are on a page for a 'Project' you'll only have access to the fields for that project node, and access to the raw node itself.

It sounds like you almost want to have global fields stored in another content type. I would do this by creating a content type named 'Global fields' and then adding the fields to that.

Then in my themes .theme file, I would implement `hook_preprocess_page(&$variables)` and within there have it load my global fields node, and inject values from that node into the `$variables` array, which is then accessible from any page template.

e.g.

```
function custom_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
      $node = node_load(123);
      $variables['hero_image'] = $node->field_hero_image->entity->getFileUri();
}
```